# Lookup comma separated values in a column of a table in SQL or ADF

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have three tables as below.

Main table:

[image]

Category look up table:

[image]

Seller lookup table:

[image]

Now I want to represent my data as below

[image]

What will the easiest way to do it in a SQL select statement? I would probably like to avoid any cursor or temp tables but rather using `string_arg`,`cross apply`,`string split` kind of functions to do it within select (if possible which I tried but could not arrive to a final solution ). I can also use ADF dataflow if needed.

Comment: You want STRING_SPLIT(), if youre in 2016 or above.

Comment: Thanks Doug. If possible, can you give me some hints to do it.

Comment: here is an example. Im not doing the whole thing for you, so play around with the below and then let us know when youre having troubles figuring it out

Comment: Also didnt catch you want the output with a delimited string like that. That is, less then ideal to put it simply. I mean if thats the requirements, fine, but it seems like youre doing a whole bunch of work to break basic database design principles when it really should be a WHOLE lot simpler

Comment: I gave you the whole answer bc im waiting on stuff to finish executing. Youre welcome.

Comment: yes actually the requirement here is to make it similar to a UI where data is represented like it. Also denormalizing 4 columns out of 100 like that will make things lot harder to read (due to repetition of other 96 columns!!)

Comment: So while i wont argue requirements - delimited strings in a single column doesnt necessarily fix "denormalized" structures. In fact this is considered bad practice. The issue youre describing is trying to accomodate not having "flat tables"  where you have a shit ton of unnecessary columns when they should in fact be rows. google "flat versu tall tabloes"

Comment: I have to agree with @DougCoats here. The design you have violates 1NF which in fact is why you were struggling to write a query in the first place. If the data is properly normalized then this type of query would be painless.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Once more for those in back: **DON'T STORE COMMA-SEPARATED DATA IN COLUMNS!** You can show the user whatever you want at output time, but _don't store it that way_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment this, so here it is in answer format. This is just an example of one way to do so using outer apply. You'll have to do something similar for each table. I hope you can take it from here?

This does not address obvious design flaws in your data structure.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#this') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #this;
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Category') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Category;
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Seller') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Seller;

CREATE TABLE #Category
    (
        CategoryID int
        , CategoryName varchar(75)
    )
;

INSERT INTO #Category
    (
        CategoryID
        , CategoryName
    )
VALUES
    (12, 'grocery'),
    (13, 'books'),
    (14, 'household')
;

CREATE TABLE #Seller
    (
        SellerID int
        , SellerName varchar(75)
    )
;

INSERT INTO #Seller
    (
        SellerID
        , SellerName
    )
VALUES
    (20, 'Amazon'),
    (21, 'starwar'),
    (23, 'Amway')
;

CREATE TABLE #this
    (
        id int
        , categoryid varchar(75)
        , sellerid varchar(75)
    )
;
INSERT INTO #this 
    (
        id
        , categoryid
        , sellerid
    )
VALUES
    (1, NULL, '20,23'),
    (2, '12,13,14', NULL),
    (3, '13', '21')
;

SELECT
    MainMapping.ID
    , STRING_AGG(c.CategoryName, ',') AS Categories
    , STRING_AGG(s.SellerName, ',') AS Sellers
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t.id
            , x.value AS SellerID
            , y.value AS CategoryID
        FROM 
            #this t
            OUTER APPLY string_split(sellerid, ',') x
            OUTER APPLY string_split(categoryid, ',') y
    ) MainMapping
    LEFT JOIN #Category c ON MainMapping.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
    LEFT JOIN #Seller s ON MainMapping.SellerID = s.SellerID
GROUP BY
    MainMapping.ID
;

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#this') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #this;
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Category') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Category;
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Seller') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Seller;
```

[image]

Comment: can't thank you enough. Really appreciate your time here. Let me try it with my actual data